# iOS7 Navigation Bar + Status Bar Text Color

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios7, ios7-statusbar

I have problems with colour of text in Status Bar. I want to make colour of text white, but keep black colour on modal views.

I have next configuration:

- Storyboard with settings "Opens in 5.1" and "Project Deployment target 7.0" and "View as iOS7 and later"
- `UITabBarViewController`
- 4 `UINavigationControllers`
- Each navigation controller has custom subclass of `UIViewController` inside

Background colour of UINavigationBar set to dark via `appearance`.

`View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES`

My subclass of `UITabBarViewController` has next methods:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

These methods are called after application started.

I also have same methods calls in my `UIViewControllers` subclasses:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; // This method never called
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

I also tried to change return value of `-preferredStatusBarStyle` to `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` (well, I know that it should paint text in black, but I tried anyway)

Same thing for setting Status Bar option to Light Content in Storyboard. Doesn't work too.

I know there are a lot of questions on SO similar to mine, but proposed solutions doesn't help in my situation.

My status bar still looks like this:

[image: StatusBar]

And I want to change its colour to white =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a work around that I occasionally found right now after struggling with this issue for about 2 weeks.

```
// This is a workaround just enables white text colour in status bar in iOS7, iOS7.1
// Dont touch it until things break
// Despite this category says "draw white", colour automatically becomes black on white background w/o additional code
@interface UINavigationController (StatusBarStyle)

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (StatusBarStyle)
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
@end
// Place at the bottom of your AppDelegate.m
// Magic!
```

I need to thank people who answered this question, but I already tried these solutions and they didn't help :( This category on UINavigationController just works.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you say that `- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` is never called in your `UIViewController` subclasses. It's normal. This method is called by your root view controller. In your case, it is the `UITabBarViewController`.

You also say that you've tried to `set Status Bar option to Light Content in Storyboard`. If you look closely, you should have done that in a section named `Simulated metrics`. So as the title suggest, modifications here are simulated...

I suggest you to try to add the key `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` in your Info.plist and to set it to YES.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this in your RootViewController :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 9.